# Sum each value of an array

Tags: angularjs

I need to sum the prices in a product list, and keep the sum updated as products are added to the list.

I'm using a service because the items will be filled with objects of others arrays.  But in the code below `$scope.total` returns nothing:

Array example:
$scope.items = [
        { id:1, nome: "Nosso Café",preco: 5,like: 69, quantidade: 1, img:'img/mais_1.jpg'}
    ];

```
.controller('pedidoCtrl', function($scope, produtoService) {

    $scope.items = null;
    $scope.items = produtoService.getProdutos();

    $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    };

    $scope.$watchCollection('items', function(array) {
        var total = 0;
        if (array) {
            angular.forEach(array, function(index) {
                total += array[index].preco;
            });
        }
        $scope.total = total;
    });
})

.service('produtoService', [function() {
    var produtosLista = [];

    var addProduto = function(produto) {
        produtosLista.push(produto);
    };

    var getProdutos = function() {
        return produtosLista;
    };
    return {
        addProduto: addProduto,
        getProdutos: getProdutos,
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you mean to add your product totals to the `resultado` variable? And then assign it to `$scope.total`?

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function(array) {
     var total = 0;
     if (array) {
         angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
             total += item.preco;
         });
     }
     $scope.total = resultado;
 });
```

or you can do

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function(array) {
     if (array) {
         $scope.total = array.reduce(function(total,item) {
             return total + item.preco;
         },0);
     } 
});
```

Comment: pls see the new version, im stupid, i was change some things and i forgot to back

Comment: @FelipeCustódio pls see updated answer. I missed your incorrect usage of the .forEach function. Please see the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach forEach takes the array element parameter first, then the index (optional).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function(array) {
    var total = 0;
    if (array) {
        angular.forEach(array, function(value) {
            total += value.preco;
        });
    }
    $scope.total = total;
});
```

Comment: sorry I was changing a fill things before and I forgot to back, but even fixing doesnt working

Comment: Thank you I will try too

Comment: hi @FelipeCustódio if you find it helpful please accept my solution, or if you have more problem i can help you more